# Query a validation within another and bring the filtered data PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I need to group all the results of an external table and only return the users that do not have the completed status

I have the following query.

```
SELECT * from tasks
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT td.task_id, td.user_id FROM tasks 
  LEFT JOIN tasks_data td ON tasks.id = td.task_id AND td.status 
    NOT IN ('Complete')) tasks_data ON tasks_data.task_id = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.id=46337;
```

The relationship in database is as follows:

A task has many users.
A user has many comments. (tasks_data)

I need to get all the users who have not typed the status Completed

EJ:

```
| Task_id | User_id | Status   |
|---------|---------|----------|
| 46337   | 158     | Pending  |
| 46337   | 1       | Pending  |
| 46337   | 158     | Complete |
| 46337   | 55      | Pending  |
| 46337   | 58      | Pending  |
| 46337   | 1       | Complete |
```

You should receive the following result:

```
| Task_id | User_id | Status  |
|---------|---------|---------|
| 46337   | 55      | Pending |
| 46337   | 58      | Pending |
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query works on your example table. (under "EJ:" text)

```
SELECT * FROM tasks_data
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id FROM tasks_data WHERE status = 'Complete'
)
AND task_id = 46337;
```

Comment: Thank you. In your query, just missing ID to Id. If necessary, it would bring empty data

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to filter the results as follows

```
select *
from tasks
left join tasks_users tu on tasks.id = tu.task_id
left join tasks_data td ON td.task_id=tasks.id
WHERE
tu.user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id FROM tasks_data WHERE tasks_data.status = 'Complete' and tasks_data.task_id = tasks.id
)
```